# ArcGIS Data Driven Pages Creates PDF in Random Order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf, data-driven-pages

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 and Data Driven Pages to create a 130 page atlas.  The export to PDF works (exported to a single PDF), but the order of the PDFs seems to be random.  There is an ESRI shapefile that serves as the index grid, and the records in this shapefile are in numerical order.  Why does the export not export to PDF in numerical order? How do I get the PDF to build in numerical order without having to do it manually?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include details of what you've set for page sort order, and a sample screenshot of the attribute table showing the contents of this field.  Remember if your sort field is a Text field the numbers won't sort fully numerically but from left to right.

Comment: don't delete your question - it can still serve to help others

Comment: Would be better to post an answer to your question - self answers are acceptable (and [encouraged](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)) here

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the sort order drop down box in the Data Driven Pages toolbar was set to FID and not to the attribute that contained the numerical orders.  My bad-problem solved.